# Unable to Run Jenkins in tomcat which already host other webapplication

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, jenkins

When I tried to deploy Jenkins.war file in Tomcat7.0.1 server I was able to deploy it without any hassle and i am able to access Jenkins with local:8080/jenkins/ URL. In the above case, I did not had any other application already deployed.

But When I tried to deploy the same Jenkins.war in another tomcat server with version 6.0 which had already running web applications did not gave any error during deployment, but i was not able to access jenkins with the URL - localhost:8080/jenkins/ and neither the application was appearing on the web console as deployed, but the exploded war was found under the tomcat folder /webapp

I searched for solutions and got some hints pertaining to port number issue but did not clearly got what need to be done.

References made:

[How to configure Jenkins to run on port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330367/how-to-configure-jenkins-to-run-on-port-80) (Not really getting what is being mentioned over here)

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins (Does not relates to Tomcat Server)

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tomcat (Provides great details in relation with Tomcat)

Comment: Currently i am not able to access the logs, as the server machine is in hold of another person, I will post the logs ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

On Single port only one application will run. So Your current tomcat is already running an application on its default port 8080.So jenkis will not run on that.

Download a new tomcat zip unpack the same,edit conf/server.xml[conf folder is inside tomcat] and change connecter port to 8081 or whatever,but port must be free.

After changing the port add jenkins war to webapps of your new tomcat and start the  tomcat.Now youu can access the jenkins over 8081 port and your application as it is

Comment: Will Changing the port number in server.xml will not change port number of already deployed applications? I think it will change for all application together. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265277/how-to-start-jenkins-on-different-port-rather-than-8080-using-command-prompt-in The given link provides a solution to run Jenkins as standalone but in some other port number, but how to deploy it with different port number  in tomcat?

Comment: You will be running two tomcats.in one your application and on other your jenkins either you are doing this in  windows or linux i will suggest you to download tomcat zip and make changes in server.xml file accordingly

Comment: Do we really require two tomcat servers? Will we not be able to deploy Jenkins as an application along with other applications?

Comment: FYI - I was able to deploy both jenkins and application together in the same port in weblogic Server, I deployed jenkins as "ear"

Comment: Yes you can also deployboth on same port in that case access jenkins like ip:port/jenkins   if name of your war file is jenkins.war