# Change Jenkins port

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am trying to change the Jenkins port from default 8080 to port 80.

so I modified the file `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` and changed the variable `JENKINS_PORT="8080"` to `JENKINS_PORT="80"`.

after changing the port I restarted jenkins service by `systemctl restart jenkins` and the service status was `Active: active (exited)`.

I changed the port back to `8080` and after restart the service status was `Active: active (running)`which is good, I also tried to change the port to 8081 and the service status was `Active: active (running)` as well, just when I am trying to use port 80 the service status is `Active: active (exited)`.

I tried to verify if port 80 is in use using `netstat -pnltu | grep -i "80"`
and the port not in use, I tried to configure port 83 just for testing and I get the same behavior as port 80 configured (`Active: active (exited)`)

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

There is another solution for **Linux** systems that mentioned in Jenkins Documentation here

If Jenkins fails to start because a port is in use, run:

```
systemctl edit jenkins
```

and add the following:

```
[Service]
Environment="JENKINS_PORT=8081"
```

This will change the port from 8080 to 8081.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in below way:

```
1. Go to the directory where you installed Jenkins (by default, it's under Program Files/Jenkins)

2. Open the Jenkins.xml configuration file.

3. You can find --httpPort=8080 and replace the 8080 with the new port number.

Restart your Jenkins server.
$ jenkins.exe restart
```

You can also refer [How to configure Jenkins to run on port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330367/how-to-configure-jenkins-to-run-on-port-80)

Comment: As you can see in my details I am using a Linux instance and not Windows, I changed this parameter on my Linux instance, the `--httpPort=` parameter have a variable as a value and as I mentioned I changed this variable's value from `JENKINS_PORT="8080"` to `JENKINS_PORT="80"`

Comment: @Dani Wol the link that I reffered gives answer about linux instance

Comment: Tried this but in this example, they are using Ubuntu and I use Redhat distribution, some of the commands cannot executable. for example the `exec daemon`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution,
I changed the `JENKINS_USER` variable value from `jenkins` to `root` on `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`.

Then I restarted `Jenkins` service using the command:

`systemctl restart jenkins`

and the service is running.

Comment: You really do not want to be running Jenkins as root! Massive security risk. Just give jenkins sudo permission on `/usr/bin/systemctl` or `/sbin/service`. That lets root stop/start Jenkins, but Jenkins app runs as jenkins user; [much more secure](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/securing-jenkins/)

Comment: Yeah, finally I installed Nginx and forward port 80 to 8080 and keep the jenkins_user parameter to jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Ports 0-1024 are reserved for the operating system and core services - services running as root.

Sounds like you are following the Jenkins install instructions which suggest creating a jenkins user and group - this is why you can run the app on 8080 and others greater than 1024.

Depending on your OS, edit your jenkins.service file and change these settings there.

On Centos, edit `/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service` or `systemctl edit jenkins` to make modifications to these settings. Better practice would be to use `systemctl edit..` when editing systemd files.

Answer (score 0):

To change Default Port of Jenkins in Windows while using jenkins.war use httpPort, I have created a small [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qH2gmXZNtUg).